# Where to implement XSS prevention in symfony-based REST API and Vue.js front-end

Tags: rest, api, symfony, vue.js, xss

I'm building an application that requires html tags to be allowed for user comments in Vue.js. 
I wan't to allow users to input a certain selection of HTML tags(p, i, ul, li) and escape/sanitize other like script or div.

Right now I see three ways of dealing with this issue:

- On rendering the content with Vue.js
- Before sending the response in Symfony(I'm using JMS Serializer)
- Upon receiving request to the API

Personally I think that we could save the data to database with tags like script or div, and just sanitize them before sending a response.

Basically my question is where should I implement the prevention and should I allow tags like script into my database?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If you're using [`v-html`](https://v2.vuejs.org/v2/api/#v-html) to render the comments, then there's always the possibility of XSS. Strict HTML sanitization can mitigate the risk, but you never know.

The only surefire way to prevent XSS is to *never* use [`v-html`](https://v2.vuejs.org/v2/api/#v-html) or [`innerHTML`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Element/innerHTML). This means you'll have to parse the HTML (using [DOMParser](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/DOMParser)) and render the comments manually.

For something like this it will be easier if you write the [render function](https://v2.vuejs.org/v2/guide/render-function.html) manually so you have full control over how the comment content will be rendered – only render the HTML tags you choose. Whitelist instead of blacklist.

Don't render user-defined HTML attributes.

HTML sanitization won't be necessary on the server because the HTML will never be rendered as-is in the browser, but you can still sanitize it if you want to trim the fat beforehand.

Here's a basic example:

```js
Vue.component('comment-content', {
  functional: true,
  
  props: {
    html: {},
    allowedElements: {
      default: () => ['p', 'i', 'b', 'ul', 'li'],
    },
  },
  
  render(h, ctx) {
    const { html, allowedElements } = ctx.props;
  
    const renderNode = node => {
      switch (node.nodeType) {
        case Node.TEXT_NODE: return renderTextNode(node);
        case Node.ELEMENT_NODE: return renderElementNode(node);
      }
    };
    
    const renderTextNode = node => {
      return node.nodeValue;
    };
    
    const renderElementNode = node => {
      const tag = node.tagName.toLowerCase();
      if (allowedElements.includes(tag)) {
        const children = [...node.childNodes].map(node => renderNode(node));
        return h(tag, children);
      }
    };
    
    const parser = new DOMParser();
    const doc = parser.parseFromString(html, 'text/html');
    return [...doc.body.childNodes].map(node => renderNode(node));
  },
});

new Vue({
  el: '#app',
  data: {
    html: `
      <p>Paragraph</p>
      <ul>
        <li>One <script>alert('Hacked')<\/script></li>
        <li onmouseover="alert('Hacked')">Two</li>
        <li style="color: red">Three <b>bold</b> <i>italic</i></li>
        <li>Four <img src="javascript:alert('Hacked')"></li>
      </ul>
      <section>This element isn't allowed</section>
      <p>Last paragraph</p>
    `,
  },
});
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/vue/2.5.17/vue.js"></script>

<div id="app">
  <comment-content :html="html"></comment-content>
</div>
```